# (Joint pmf) drawing balls from a urn with replacement and adding

Tags: probability, statistics

The question is the following:

> Suppose an urn initially contains one red ball, one blue ball, and one
> green ball. At each draw, a ball is randomly selected from the urn,
> replaced, and an additional ball of the same color as the drawn ball
> is added to the urn. We need to find the joint probability mass
> function of the random vector $(X, Y, Z)$ where $X, Y,$ are Z are the number
> of times a red, blue, green ball was drawn, respectively.

The solution first find out the probability that a total number of x, y, and z draws of red, blue, green balls of a particular sequence of n draws is $$\frac{2x!y!z!}{(n+2)!}$$ But to find the joint pmf, we need to multiply the probability above with $\frac{n!}{x!y!z!}$
I'm confused about what is the purpose of multiplying $\frac{n!}{x!y!z!}$, $P(X,Y,Z)=\frac{n!}{x!y!z!}*\frac{2x!y!z!}{(n+2)!}$ is obvious the correct answer but how can I get this equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we wish to compute the probability of drawing $x$ red, $y$ blue, and $z$ green balls in a *specific* order. As per the conditions, starting with 1 of each color and adding a ball of the last chosen color after each selection, convince yourself the probability of this event is simply

$$\small \left(\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{2}{4}\cdot...\cdot\frac{x}{x+2}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{1}{x+3}\cdot \frac{2}{x+4}\cdot...\cdot\frac{y}{x+y+2}\right)
\left(\frac{1}{x+y+3}\cdot \frac{2}{x+y+4}\cdot...\cdot\frac{z}{x+y+z+2}\right),$$

and letting $n=x+y+z$ denote the total draws, this is simply

$$\frac{2x!y!z!}{(n+2)!}.\qquad [1]$$

Now, to find the probability of drawing $x$ red, $y$ blue, and $z$ green in *any* order, we  need to count all the different orderings in which we could have drawn these balls, i.e. count the number of ways to rearrange the following sequence of length $n$:

$$\underbrace{R...R}_{x \text{ of these}}\quad \underbrace{B...B}_{y \text{ of these}}\quad \underbrace{G...G}_{z \text{ of these}}.$$

There are $\frac{n!}{x!y!z!}$ such permutations because there are $n!$ ways to arrange a list of $n$ distinct items, but to avoid overcounting, we must divide out the ways to rearrange the indistinguishable duplicates of each color (there are $x!$ ways to rearrange the $R$s etc.).

So multiplying the number of permutations by the probability in $[1]$ gives us the probability of drawing our $x$ red, $y$ blue, and $z$ green balls in any order, as desired:

$$\frac{n!}{x!y!z!}\frac{2x!y!z!}{(n+2)!}=\frac{n!2}{(n+2)!}. $$

Note that when order doesn't matter, this probability doesn't depend on how many balls of each color we draw; it only depends on our total draws.